# requested URL is not found this server? doesn't redirect to the next php page

Tags: php, html

Good evening everyone i'm working on a stock market simulation using php ...and i've few errors that i can't reslove ..
1- after i submit log in credentials i get to get this message 
Not Found

The requested URL /viewdetails.php was not found on this server.

i'm using wamp server ..so if i want to proceed to "viewdetails.php" i have to add the folder name in which the project is at manually to the URL for instance URL Test/viewdetails.php

so here is the code for both of the php pages ! to start with is the "index.php"

```
 <?php
require("functions_start.php");

if (isset($_REQUEST["username"]) && isset($_REQUEST["password"]))
{
    $error = $theUser->LoginCheck($_REQUEST["username"], $_REQUEST["password"]);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST["logout"]))
    $theUser->Logout();

if (isset($_SESSION["authenticated"]) && $_SESSION["authenticated"]== true)
{
    header("Location: /viewdetails.php");
    exit;
}

HTMLHeader("Login to the stocks!",false);

if (isset($error))
{
    if ($error==false)
        echo "<div>Not able to login, please try again</div>";
}
if (isset($_REQUEST["logout"])) 
    echo "Thanks for using the site, you are logged out!";
?>
```

-

```
<div id="login">
  <b class="rtop">
    <b class="r1"></b> <b class="r2"></b> <b class="r3"></b> <b class="r4"></b>
  </b>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" onsubmit="">
  Login
  <p>
    Username : <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=
  "<?php echo           $_REQUEST["username"]; ?>"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    Password : <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </p>
  <p id="right">
    <a href="register.php">Register</a> here.
  </p>
  </form>
  <b class="rbottom">
    <b class="r4"></b> <b class="r3"></b> <b class="r2"></b> <b class="r1"></b>
  </b>
</div>
<?php
HTMLFooter();
?>
```

and this is a part form the "viewdetails.php"

```
<?php
require("functions_start.php");

global $theStock;

if (!isset($_SESSION["authenticated"]) || $_SESSION["authenticated"]== false)
{
    header("Location: /index.php");
    exit;
}
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
    if (strpos($key, "remove_") === 0)
        $theStock->SellStock($_SESSION["username"], $value);
    if ($key=="stock")
        $getStock = $value;
}
HTMLHeader("The details of your account");
   ?>
```

Comment: I have to ask, but is there a reason you're using the $_REQUEST super global and not the one defined in your form method, $_POST? Additionally, where is index.php located? If it's at the webroot itself, then it's going to run just fine, and then if your viewdetails script is in a child directory, you're going to hit this error.

Comment: Firstly, is `session_start();` included anywhere in your files? It's not shown/mentioned anywhere.

Comment: If the `viewdetails.php` file doesn't exist, then your code has done its job. Using `header("Location: /viewdetails.php");` with a starting `/` may not be the best method to use. Try using the full `http` call such as `header("Location: http://www.example.com/viewdetails.php");` then the rest is pure debugging.

Comment: @Fred-ii- 'Yes session_start();' is included in another .php file where if my user loggedIn = True using HTMLHeader function then it will proceed with the viewdetails html contents!

Comment: Another thing which may be at play is `onsubmit=""` remove it. That could be preventing it from submitting properly.

Comment: Is `session_start();` inside `all` your files? Including `viewdetails.php`

Comment: Also, since you're using this on a `localhost` machine, and if all your files are in your root, then take out the `/` in `header("Location: /viewdetails.php");` to be as `header("Location: viewdetails.php");` that could be a factor. I can't see anything else being problematic.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have session_start(); in on file only where i start require most of the other files ! ...i tried removing on sumbit but no luck ...i also tried the http call with the whole path still no luck

Comment: @Zarazthuztra the index.php is located right next to my project other files in a folder ...and this folder is in wamp root folder which www by default!

Comment: @user3075639 I don't understand what you're saying. Basically, the way you have referred to viewdetails.php above is by saying /viewdetails.php. That string refers to the webroot, not the directory which viewdetails is in.

Comment: `session_start();` must be inside ALL files.

Comment: You said the url is "Test/viewdetails.php"? then the redirect should go to "/test/viewdetails.php", it's not clear what are your urls

Comment: @arieljuod i mean that if i want to bypass the server error i just type the folder's name before ..when i get the error my url is URL /viewdetials.php , if i add the folder's name before it works !

Comment: and how do you access the index file? test/index.php? i mean, explain your url, where is index? where do you want to go? full urls, with host and everything, that way we can help you better, I think the problem is just a wrong url for the redirect